# How to unlock windows registry hive?

Tags: windows-registry, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am running `Windows 11 20H2` and I opened a registry hive related to `Visual Studio 2022` for [this purpose](https://www.davici.nl/blog/disable-visual-studio-2022-iis-security-attach-warning). A little later I closed the registry, forgetting to first unload that hive. Now it seems stuck - I can neither load the hive again, nor unload it. **I tried rebooting my PC**, but no luck.

[image]

[image]

I regret my mistake, but this seems irreversible at this point and I am jacked. There must be a way to solve this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Restart, run DISM / SFC, restart and see if that corrects the issue. ........  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Try to boot in Safe mode to unload it.